# VIM Ale pylint Warnings hide flake8 Error messages

Tags: vim, pylint, flake8

I am using Ale with pylint and flake8. I observed the following behavior:

Function `test` at line 6 (image 1) has a number of pylint warnings: `Too many arguments` (cursor over letter `d` -> `def`) and `Unused argument` (cursor over `a` for each argument `arg`)

[image]

At the same time there is a flak8 Error: `error| [flake8] E303: too many blank lines (3) [Error]`. The flake8 error is hidden and not showing until the warning(s) are resolved.

If I resolve the `Unused argument` warnings, still the flake8 error does not appear
[image]

Let me also resolve the `Too many arguments` warning even though in a real time scenario this warning cannot be resolved since you might need all these args. In such a case the flake8 error will stay hidden forever.

[image]

Now the error appears.

Is there any way to avoid this behavior? It hides errors and the only way to find this error is to do `:lopen`. But this approach makes the visual signs in vim's gutter redundant since it means you cannot trust what you see and you always have to do `:lopen`.

Can we echo all error messages of the same line at the same time in the status line? Or prioritize them somehow? What is the best way to handle such situations?